# how to close the ant-design-vue select option on mouse leave?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, antd

```
<a-select
    showSearch
    placeholder="Select a person"
    optionFilterProp="children"
    style="width: 200px"
    :open="open"
    @mouseenter="openSelect"
    @mouseleave="closeSelect"
  >
    <a-select-option value="jack">Jack</a-select-option>
    <a-select-option value="lucy">Lucy</a-select-option>
    <a-select-option value="tom">Tom</a-select-option>
  </a-select>
</template>

data() {
  open: false,
}

methods: {
  openSelect() {
    this.open = true;
  }
  closeSelect() {
    this.open = false;
  }
}
```

how to close a ant-design-vue select option when the user is no longer using it? i've tried by using onBlur and onMouseLeave. and also i have tried with create a function onFocus() {this.open = true} and function for onBlur(){ this.open=false } but still not work

the mouseleaveevent will be triggered after pointer is not in the field but the option still not be able to choose

Answer (score 1):

http://vue.ant-design.cn/components/select/#events

according to the doc of select component, there is a `mouseleave` event supported.
try using `@mouseleave="foo"` to set options invisible

Comment: i've already made that in the updated question. but the function is not working as in updated question

Comment: your code is `:mouseleave="closeSelect"` instead of `@mouseleave="closeSelect"`,the `mouseleave` is an event rather than a prop

Comment: yes i have recorrect that. but still there is a problem which the user did not able to select. because when the pointer going out from the field to choose the option it's automatically close. which handler is a better to make this work?

Comment: so the mouseleave event emit when cursor leaves the field, but you want to recive the event when cursor leaves options popup. so you should register the event listener manually and remove the `mouseleave` handler

Comment: i've added window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.closeSelect); in created() and destroyed() but there is nothing affected

Comment: Inspect your dom element and find the class name of the popper, use document.querySelector to get the element and add mouse leave event listener to it